# Ajax data being returned slow

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am calling a PHP page with Ajax. I noticed that when there is a lot of data being returned (almost 5000 lines), it takes a few seconds for the page to load. Is this normal behavior? Here is the code I am using to call it:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '_get_items.php?project_id=<?=$_GET['project_id']?>&list_id=<?=$_GET['list_id']?>&sort='+ sort +'&assigned_to='+ assigned_to,
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.tasks_items').html(data);

        }
    });
```

When I debug it in Chrome, the majority of the time it is spent on "XHR Ready State Change" and "Recalculate Style" is called a couple hundred times.

[image]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyCa1.png)

I am sure that the reason it is so slow is because of all the data being returned. My question is, how can this be fixed? Should I minify the HTML? GZip is already enabled. Any other suggestions?

Here is the Network screen:

[image]
[Full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsTMB.png)

Comment: What are you sending back to the server? Don't worry about recalculate style, paint, or layout.

Comment: are you using all 5000 lines of code?  Is there a way to minimize the amount of data sent back?  maybe with paging or something?

Comment: It is mainly tables and forms (a lot of them). Unfortunately for what I'm doing, I do need them all on one screen, I can't paginate them. If I convert the tables to divs using CSS, would that remove the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1):

Check the network debug panel. It will show you where the request spents it's time. Whether it is waiting for the server response, and/or receiving the data. If it is waiting for the response most of the time, you'd need to profile your server side code. If it is receiving, you'd need to think about how to make the payload smaller.

Comment: Unfortunately the networking screen didn't provide anything helpful (I edited my original question with a screenshot of it). I have used xdebug to create the cachegrind.out files and have analyzed them but I don't believe the bottleneck is in my PHP code.

Comment: I don't see the _get_items.php request in that plot. But it maybe due to the low resolution of the image. Anyways, make sure you have the debug panel open when this request is made. If you hover over the time bar of the request you see detailed timing information, more information (headers, payload, timing) is available if you click on the request in the left column.

Comment: I updated the screenshot with a better one (and added the full sized links). The ms is pretty low compared to how many seconds it took. There is a big gap on the graph.

Comment: The request is not an issue, that is quick. You need to figure out where that delay comes from. I'd probably start doing something differently in your success function, e.g. append the payload to your page in a new div. BTW, how long is the list of selected elements of your '.tasks_item' selector. If that is long, it may be very expensize, you are setting a payload of ~280KB a couple of times - $.html sets the html of every element you've matched with the selector.

Comment: Worked for me! One telltale sign that it was the server side code that was busy is I had multiple requests all delayed at once, then they all completed together.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that using raw JavaScript is faster than a library when appending large blocks of HTML:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '_get_items.php?project_id=<?=$_GET['project_id']?>&list_id=<?=$_GET['list_id']?>&sort='+ sort +'&assigned_to='+ assigned_to,
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
        $('.tasks_items').get(0).innerHtml = data;
    }
});
```